# Trouble importing foundation into swift... Xcode 6 beta

Tags: xcode, swift

I am brand new to Xcode. Thank you for reading this.

I'm simply attempting to get used to the language, so I'm simply messing with code by importing Foundation and creating a simple NSRect. However, I'm getting an error when I try to create NSRect.

Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
let rect = NSRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

And then I receive an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSRect"." What am I doing incorrectly?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wrote the code you used and had no errors, what type of application is it. Console app or are you using Playground?

Comment: It's a single view iOS app, not in playground. I created a blank swift file within the project and put that code in there.

Comment: If you want to get moving just use CGRect because NSRect is just a typelias for CGRect. "typealias NSRect = CGRect"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **CGRect** instead of **NSRect** . **NSRect** is for **Cocoa**, if project is for mac app use `import Cocoa`.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
let rect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: And bear in mind that if you're in a playground, just swapping "import UIKit" to "import Cocoa" won't be enough. Each playground has a specific type; you can use the File Inspector in Xcode to change a playground from "iOS" to "OS X", under "Playground Settings". If you don't do this in a playground, the symptom will be that "import Cocoa" or "import UIKit" will tell you "No such module..." if you have the wrong type selected.